# List Ldap servers in the domain and authenticate

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

How to get List of LDAP servers given a domain name (using java + acitvedirectory) , and authenticate it based on username and password ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Here are the steps to do it

### GET Server List

1. Hit DNS server to get SRV records
2. Sort SRV records
3. Filter server record based on regexp pattern
4. Construct LDAP urls based on if we need ssl or not. **Note** that srv record can return only one port so dont rely on port returned from srv record.  See  [srv record RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt)

### Authentication

1. iterate through list of servers

   1. Construct Hashtable with ldap environments. note that need to append domain name with username separated by \, and add ldap URL to it
   2. try to create InitialDirContext
   3. **success :** close context and return
   4. **failure1 :** if naming exception is AuthenticationException and contains messge *"[LDAP: error code 49"* translate and throw a readable exception ! see [error code mapping](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631)
   5. **failure2 :** if not failure1 continue with next ldap URL

---

## And Here is the full fledged working code

If you are using spring use following conf to invoke init method

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass">
        <value>org.bhate.ldap.LdapUtil</value>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="init" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>${ldap.dnsServer}</value>
            <value>${ldap.domainName}</value>
            <value>${ldap.filter.regexp}</value>
            <value>${ldap.ssl}</value>
        </list>         
    </property>
```

And Following properties

```
ldap.dnsServer=uk.mydomain.com
ldap.domainName=DOMAINNAME
ldap.filter.regexp=serv10.*|server.*
ldap.ssl=true
```

else call init during startup

```
LdapUtil.init("uk.mydomain.com", "DOMAINNAME", "serv10.*|server.*",true);
```

**LdapUtil.java**

```
package org.bhate.ldap;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.spi.NamingManager;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils;
import org.springframework.security.BadCredentialsException;


public class LdapUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LdapUtil.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    final static Map<String, String> errorCodesMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put("525", "user not found");
            put("52e", "invalid credentials");
            put("530", "not permitted to logon at this time");
            put("531", "not permitted to logon at this workstation");
            put("532", "password expired");
            put("533", "account disabled");
            put("701", "account expired");
            put("773", "user must reset password");
            put("775", "user account locked");
        }
    };

    private static Collection<String> ldapServers;
    private static String domainName;
    private static Pattern PATTERN;

    public static DirContext getDirContext(String url, String domainName,
            String userName, String password) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = getEnv(url, domainName, userName,
                password);
        return new InitialDirContext(env);
    }

    public static Collection<String> getLdapServers(String ldapDomain,
            boolean useSsl) throws NamingException {
        Collection<String> serverRecords = getSRVRecords(ldapDomain);
        serverRecords = reOrder(serverRecords);
        Collection<String> serverNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        String protocol = "ldap" + (useSsl ? 's' : "");
        for (String s : serverRecords) {
            String hostName = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1,
                    s.length() - 1);
            serverNames.add(protocol + "://" + hostName);
        }
        return serverNames;
    }

    private static Collection<String> reOrder(Collection<String> serverRecords) {
        return serverRecords;
    }

    private static Collection<String> getSRVRecords(String ldapDomain)
            throws NamingException {
        DirContext context = (DirContext) NamingManager.getURLContext("dns",
                new Hashtable<String, Object>());
        String ldapDNSUrl = "dns:///_ldap._tcp." + ldapDomain;
        String[] attrIds = { "SRV" };
        Attributes attributes = context.getAttributes(ldapDNSUrl, attrIds);
        Attribute servers = attributes.get("SRV");
        int L = servers.size();
        Collection<String> serverRecords = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
            String s = (String) servers.get(i);
            if (PATTERN.matcher(s).find())
                serverRecords.add(s);
        }
        return serverRecords;
    }

    public static void authenticate(String userName, String password) {
        String msg = "Unable authenticate user {} with {}";
        for (String url : ldapServers) {
            DirContext ctx = null;
            try {
                ctx = getDirContext(url, domainName, userName, password);
                LOGGER
                        .info("Authenticated user {} on server {}", userName,
                                url);
                return;
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                LOGGER.error(msg, userName, url);
                String m = NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(e.getMessage(), e
                        .getCause());
                LOGGER.error(m, e);
                if (e instanceof AuthenticationException
                        && e.getMessage().startsWith("[LDAP: error code 49"))
                    throwMeanigfulEx(userName, url, e);
            } finally {
                close(ctx);
            }
        }
        LOGGER.error(msg, userName, "any available server");
        throw new BadCredentialsException(
                "Unable to authenticate : Please contact application support team");
    }

    public static void init(String dnsServerName, String domainName,
            String serverFilter, boolean useSsl) {
        PATTERN = Pattern.compile(serverFilter);
        try {
            LdapUtil.domainName=domainName;
            ldapServers = getLdapServers(dnsServerName, useSsl);

            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info(
                        "LDAP servers available in domain {} to connect {}",
                        dnsServerName, ldapServers);
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable retrieve ldapServers for "
                    + dnsServerName, e);
        }
    }

    private static void throwMeanigfulEx(String userName, String url,
            NamingException e) {
        String separator = ", data ";
        String m = e.getMessage();
        int strt = m.lastIndexOf(separator) + separator.length();
        int end = m.lastIndexOf(", vece");
        String code = m.substring(strt, end);
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Unable to authenticate : "
                + errorCodesMap.get(code));
    }

    private static void close(DirContext ctx) {
        if (ctx != null)
            try {
                ctx.close();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to close context", e);
            }
    }

    private static Hashtable<String, Object> getEnv(String url,
            String domainName, String userName, String password) {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "2000");
        // env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.trace.ber", System.err);
        // env.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        // env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, getPrincipal(domainName, userName));
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        return env;
    }

    private static Object getPrincipal(String domainName, String userName) {
        return domainName + "\\" + userName;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        init("uk.mydomain.com", "DOMAINNAME", "serv10.*|server.*",true);
        System.out.println(ldapServers.size());
        System.out.println(ldapServers);
        if (args.length == 2)
            authenticate(args[0], args[1]);
    }


    //
    // public static InitialLdapContext getLdapContext(String userName,
    // String domainName, String password, String url)
    // throws NamingException {
    // Hashtable<String, Object> env = getEnv(url, domainName, userName,
    // password);
    // Control[] connCtls = new Control[] { new Control() {
    // private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //
    // public byte[] getEncodedValue() {
    // return null;
    // }
    //
    // public String getID() {
    // return "1.2.840.113556.1.4.1781";
    // }
    //
    // public boolean isCritical() {
    // return true;
    // }
    // } };
    // return new InitialLdapContext(env, connCtls);
    // }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet for looking up SRV records in Java, use it with the domain given by ShaMan (`_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.your.domain.com`).

```
private static final String[] SRV = new String[] { "SRV" };

public static Collection<InetSocketAddress> srv(String name)
    throws NamingException
{
    DirContext ctx = new IntialDirContext();

    Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes("dns:/" + name, SRV);
    if(attributes.get("SRV") == null)
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    NamingEnumeration<?> e = attributes.get("SRV").getAll();
    TreeMap<Integer, InetSocketAdress> result = new TreeMap<Integer, InetSocketAdress>();

    while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String line = (String) e.nextElement();

        // The line is priority weight port host
        String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");

        int prio = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int port = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        String host = parts[3];

        result.put(prio, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    }

    return result.values();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of LDAP servers for a given AD domain by reading the SRV records for that domain. The SRV record you need have value similar to this one `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.your.domain.com`. This article should give you some more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738991%28WS.10%29.aspx.

You can use JNDI to retrieve the DNS information and later to authenticate via LDAP. A nice tutorial can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/.